# php array to JQuery .live for multiple pairs of values or?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm starting over here...

### This is generated....

```
<form name="ratePage">
<input id="service" type="text" value="Ground"><input id="rate" value="" type="text" size="6"><input type="submit" name="BtnAction" value="Select" onclick="SubmitValue();"><br>
<input id="service" type="text" value="3 Day Select"><input id="rate" value="" type="text" size="6"><input type="submit" name="BtnAction" value="Select" onclick="SubmitValue();"><br>
<input id="service" type="text" value="2nd Day Air"><input id="rate" value="" type="text" size="6"><input type="submit" name="BtnAction" value="Select" onclick="SubmitValue();"><br>
<input id="service" type="text" value="2nd Day Air AM"><input id="rate" value="" type="text" size="6"><input type="submit" name="BtnAction" value="Select" onclick="SubmitValue();"><br>
<input id="service" type="text" value="Next Day Air Saver"><input id="rate" value="" type="text" size="6"><input type="submit" name="BtnAction" value="Select" onclick="SubmitValue();"><br>
<input id="service" type="text" value="Next Day Air"><input id="rate" value="" type="text" size="6"><input type="submit" name="BtnAction" value="Select" onclick="SubmitValue();"><br>
<input id="service" type="text" value="Next Day Air (early AM)"><input id="rate" value="" type="text" size="6"><input type="submit" name="BtnAction" value="Select" onclick="SubmitValue();"><br></form>
```

### From this...

```
<?php 
foreach($services as $name=>$value){
            $service = $value;
            $rate = $myRate->getRate($fromzip, $tozip, $service, $length, $width, $height, $weight);

            echo "<input id=\"service\" type=\"text\" value=\"$name\"><input id=\"rate\" value=\"$rate\" type=\"text\" size=\"6\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"BtnAction\" value=\"Select\" onclick=\"SubmitValue();\"><br>\n";
        }
?>
```

### The Output looks like this...

[image: OUTPUT]

### I want to turn this... (this is in the generated forms page)

```
<script language="javascript"> 

function SubmitValue(){
opener.document.orderForm.rate.value = document.ratePage.rate.value;
opener.document.orderForm.service.value = document.ratePage.service.value;
self.close();

</script>
```

Into a Jquery `.live` function that will copy ONLY the selected values from the selected row.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: One of the issues with your foreach... you'll have multiple fields with the same `id` attribute. Aside from being bad HTML, you won't be able to target your elements using names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make each row look like:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="abc" class="service">
    <input class="rate" value="222" type="text" size="6">
    <input type="submit" name="BtnAction" class="submit" value="Select">
</div>
```

Then you can use

```
$('.submit').live('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    opener.document.orderForm.rate.value = $this.siblings(".rate").val();
    opener.document.orderForm.service.value = $this.siblings(".service").val();
    self.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See PHP's `json_encode()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) since it looks like what you're doing should be a simple AJAX response. I would highly recommend using jQuery's AJAX API to handle the client-side logic. Your PHP script simply needs to output your array data JSON encoded with a mime type of `application/json`.

Comment: I'll look into that a bit more, but I think you missed the main part of my question. Once the items are returned, the user must select one of them and have that value copy back to the window.opener.

Comment: When the select is clicked, you could traverse the DOM to find the two input fields next to the submit button and grab their values from there.